# Hiding the "Table of Contents" page from Table of Contents

Tags: table-of-contents, memoir

I'm using the `memoir` class, and it adds the Table of Contents page to the TOC. It is... well... pretty redundant...

Any quick way to eliminate this?

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\tableofcontents

\mainmatter
\chapter{A Chapter}
\end{document}
```

[image: Demonstration of contents in contents.]

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to remove the self-reference of the ToC from the ToC?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10943/how-to-remove-the-self-reference-of-the-toc-from-the-toc)

Comment: @Caramdir Doesn't this question predate the one you refer to? (Implying that the other one is the duplicate).

Comment: @mforbes: The other had a MWE and both ways to solve the problem as answers, so I thought it better to keep that one. (I see that you improved lockstep's answer here.)

Comment: @Caramdir I figured it was best to go with the earliest example. I will add a MWE if this one should be kept.

Comment: @mforbes: Doesn't really matter, but one should be closed. Since the OP of this question is more active, it might be better to close this other one.

Comment: @ Caramdir Okay.  I've suggested updates to this question and answer giving MWE's and both solutions.  I would vote to close all other duplicates: [10943](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10943/), [47225](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47225], and the latest [50031](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/50031).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use the starred command version `\tableofcontents*` instead of `\tableofcontents`.  This effectively places the command in a `KeepFromToc` environment, providing an alternate verbose solution (see pages 151 and 158 of the memoir manual):

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\begin{KeepFromToc}        % or simply \tableofcontents* 
  \tableofcontents
\end{KeepFromToc}

\mainmatter
\chapter{A Chapter}
\end{document}
```

[image: Working solution.]