# How to remove the self-reference of the ToC from the ToC?

Tags: table-of-contents, memoir

I'm having a very weird problem. The following example should illustrate it quite right.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{memoir}    
\begin{document}
\frontmatter
  \tableofcontents
  \clearpage
\mainmatter
  \chapter{Chapter 1}
\end{document}
```

I've compiled it with `xelatex` but on the table of contents page, it is referencing the table of contents page as *Contents*, which is the header of that page as well. It does make sense to me to a certain extend. But I'd still like to know how to get rid of the self-reference.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to remove double "Contents" heading generated by memoir?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47225/how-to-remove-double-contents-heading-generated-by-memoir)

Comment: And duplicate of [Hiding the “Table of Contents” page from Table of
Contents (3879)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3879/) (the first instance I
think), and [How to remove the self-reference of the ToC from the
ToC?(10943)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10943/).

Answer (score 37, accepted):

`\KeepFromToc` helps in suppressing TOC entries for such `\listof` commands:

```
\begin{KeepFromToc}
  \tableofcontents
\end{KeepFromToc}
```

Comment: It's a memoir class feature.

Comment: I'll accept this as the answer as it's `memoire` specific which was my initial problem. It should be noted though that both answers provide a working solution.

Answer (score 35):

Thanks to Martin Scharrer, I paid a more attention to the `memoir` class as the source of the issue.

A closer examination of [the memoir README](http://dante.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/memoir/README) reveals `\tableofcontents*` as a solution. Seems logical, everything I want to hide gets the star.

Comment: I was just going to post `\tableofcontents*` as a solution. (I found it by `\show\tableofcontents`, NOT be reading the 583 pages-manual.).

Comment: Well, that doesn't work for me in the memoir class :|
I can see that it should work according to v1.61803398, but...

Answer (score 19):

I suggest you, if using the `tocbibind` package:

```
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
```

Comment: Did you actually test this?

Comment: Worked for me, using a class based off of `report`. In my case, `tocbibind` (which I was using to include my figure and table lists in the TOC) was what caused the TOC to appear in the TOC in the first place.

Comment: Works for me on Overleaf with document class `article`.

Comment: Worked for me, too. I am using the `scrbook` class.

Comment: This worked for me using `book` class. Issue was I had used `\usepackage{tocbibind}` to get the bibliography to appear in the table of contents, without realizing until much later that it made "contents" appear there too, until adding `[nottoc]`.

Answer (score 16):

I had a similar problem, but with the article class. Neither of the solutions above work for this class, so after much searching I used the advice of Martin above and searched the article class and found that I can simply not use `\tableofcontents`, and instead use:

```
\makeatletter
\@starttoc{toc}
\makeatother
```

This doesn't create a section for the table of contents, so the problem goes away.

Thought I would post this here in case anyone else has a similar problem.

Comment: This is useful for cases where you don't want the "Contents" header above the TOC.

Answer (score 7):

The following works for supressing the self-referencing TOC entry, and is not specific to `memoir` (I'm using `scrbook`):

```
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\setcounter{tocdepth}{-1}}
\tableofcontents
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}}
```

You can of course replace the 3 with whatever tocdepth you prefer to have.