# In memoir, how can I remove the table of contents from itself, while keeping its PDF bookmarkindex?

Tags: table-of-contents, memoir, bookmarks

As suggested in [answers to existing questions](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10943/how-to-remove-the-self-reference-of-the-toc-from-the-toc), it is possible to use `tableofcontents*` or `\begin{KeepFromToc}` in order to make the table of contents not contain an entry to itself.

However, when I use these commands to avoid the ToC self-reference, the table of contents also disappears from my PDF bookmarks. Is there a way I can add back the bookmark entry for the ToC without making it reference itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

Define a hypertarget first, being the `\tableofcontents*` position and add a `\pdfbookmark` for this then. The default bookmark level is `0`, seems to be alright for a `ToC`.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage[bookmarksopen=true,bookmarksopenlevel=2]{hyperref}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}
\begin{document}
\phantomsection
\pdfbookmark{\contentsname}{toctarget}
\hypertarget{toctarget}{\tableofcontents*}

\chapter{First chapter}
\blindtext[5]
\section{First section}
\blindtext[5]
\subsection{First subsection}
\blindtext[5]
\end{document}
```

Comment: I don't suspect strange characters in the `\contentsname`, so `\texorpdfstring` isn't needed, most likely.