# Article Class: How to remove the self-reference of the ToC from the ToC?

Tags: table-of-contents, article

I have a very basic question:

> In the `article` class how can I take the hyperlink "Contents" out of the table of contents without deleting the header "Content" which is above the whole table of contents?

*[Notice that most – if not all – of the other questions on the topic are for the `memoir` class]*

The question comes because, [in this previous question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10943/how-to-remove-the-self-reference-of-the-toc-from-the-toc), I found an answer (the one made by user Ashley) whhere it was suggested to use the following code:

```
\makeatletter
\@starttoc{toc}
\makeatother
```

However, as pointed out below the answer in a comment by user Werner, the result is that you take out the selfreferential hyperlink, but also the header with the title "Content".

*Is it possible to avoid this?*

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Are you using any packages that may necessarily include the ToC in the ToC?

Comment: By default, the table of contents is not included in the TOC itself; it is if you have `\usepackage{tocbibind}`; in this case add the `nottoc` option: `\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick reply! Now that you point this, I see the problem: I am using `tocbibind` (it was a recent addition), and, when I compile without it , there is no problem. Is there a way to use it, and get rid of the things I mentioned effect.