# How to manipulate \tableofcontents

Tags: table-of-contents, tocbibind

I would like that the table of contents does not show two times the word "Contents". How can I do ? The code is below .

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{tocbibind}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[square]{natbib}
\usepackage{isotope}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{mhchem}
\usepackage{version}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{hyperref,xcolor}
\definecolor{wine-stain}{rgb}{0.5,0,0}
\hypersetup{
  colorlinks,
  linkcolor=blue,
  citecolor=blue,
  linktoc=page
}
%\hypersetup{
 %   colorlinks,
  %  citecolor=blue,
   % filecolor=blue,
    %linkcolor=blue,
%    urlcolor=blue
%    linktoc=page
%}
\begin{document}


{\centering{
        {\huge\textbf{Title} \\
        \vspace{20pt}
        {\large Author} \\
        \vspace{20pt}
        \Large Subtitle \\
        \vspace{5pt}
        {\small Date}
        \vspace{5pt}
        \hrule
        \vspace{30pt}}}}
    \tableofcontents
    \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Abstract}
    \section*{Abstract}
    \end{document}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove the self-reference of the ToC from the ToC?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10943/how-to-remove-the-self-reference-of-the-toc-from-the-toc)

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos all the examples of your link use memoir while I would like to use article

Comment: Your supposedly minimal working example did not mention any class (thereby it is not “working”, and I suppose that you will agree that it is not “minimal” either).

Comment: Sorry @JoséCarlosSantos I forgot to include in the code `\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}`  but now I have modified it .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change

```
\usepackage{tocbibind}
```

to

```
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
```

The purpose of the [tocbibind package](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/tocbibind) is to allow the inclusion of ToC, the Bibliography, and the Index in -- you guessed it -- the table of contents.

Take a look at the [user guide](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/tocbibind/tocbibind.pdf) of the tocbibind package to familiarize yourself with the package's user options -- one of which is `nottoc`.