# How to take out the Summary from the summary

Tags: table-of-contents

I'm using Overleaf to edit my final paper and there's a problem with my summary. Although I'm using the right command, it keeps showing up a sub topic on the summary called summary, indicating where it is and I don't want that. Does anyone know if there's a command that can help me out with that?

The compiler is giving me this warning and 2 other similar ones about the `\listoffigures` and `\listoftables`. I don't know if there's any relation with the problem I'm having right now.

> Package tocbasic Warning: `tocbibind` redefinition of `\tableofcontents` detected. Note: Loading `tocbibind` without option `nottoc` can break several features of `tocbasic`. Loading `tocbibind` before `tocbasic` would avoid this warning message.

This is what is happening to my document:

[image: This is the problem I want to solve]

This is the command I'm using to generate the Summary

`\tableofcontents`

This is my `pre.tex`, to format everything before I start writing the chapters:

```
\pagestyle{empty}
% Faz com que a página seguinte sempre seja ímpar (insere pg em branco)
\cleardoublepage
% Números das páginas em algarismos romanos
\pagenumbering{roman}

\singlespacing
\begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.7\textwidth]{imgs/unesp.png}
\end{figure}
\begin{center}
\vspace{60pt}
{\LARGE \nomedoaluno}
\par
\vspace{120pt}
{\Huge \titulo}
\end{center}
\par
\vspace{120pt}


\par    
\vfill
\begin{center}
\textbf{{\large São José do Rio Preto}\\
{\large 2021}}
\end{center}

\newpage


% Página de Rosto
\begin{center}
{\LARGE \nomedoaluno}
\par
\vspace{120pt}
{\Huge \titulo}
\end{center}
\par
\vspace{100pt}
\hspace*{160pt}\parbox{9cm}{{Monografia apresentada ao Departamento de Ciências de Computação e Estatística do Instituto de Biociências, Letras e Ciências Exatas da Universidade Estadual Paulista "Júlio de Mesquita Filho", como parte dos requisitos necessários para a aprovação na disciplina Trabalho de Conclusão de Curso.}}



\par
\vspace{40pt}
\hspace*{160pt}\parbox{7.6cm}{{ Orientadora:}}

\par
\vspace{1em}
\hspace*{160pt}\parbox{7.6cm}{{\large Prof. Dr. Rogéria Cristiane Gratão de Souza}}



\par
\vfill
\begin{center}
\textbf{{\large São José do Rio Preto}\\
{\large 2021}}
\end{center}



%\includepdf[pages={1}]{fichacatalografica.pdf}

\newpage

\begin{center}
{\LARGE \nomedoaluno}
\par
\vspace{120pt}
{\Huge \titulo}
\end{center}
\par
\vspace{100pt}
\hspace*{160pt}\parbox{9cm}{{Monografia apresentada ao Departamento de Ciências de Computação e Estatística do Instituto de Biociências, Letras e Ciências Exatas da Universidade Estadual Paulista "Júlio de Mesquita Filho", como parte dos requisitos necessários para a aprovação na disciplina Trabalho de Conclusão de Curso.}}



\par
\vspace{10pt}


\par
\vspace{40pt}
\hspace*{160pt}\parbox{7.6cm}{{ Banca Avaliadora:}}

\par
\vspace{1em}
\hspace*{160pt}\parbox{7.6cm}{{\large Rogéria Cristiane Gratão de Souza}}

\par
\vspace{1em}
\hspace*{160pt}\parbox{7.6cm}{{\large Adriana Barbosa Santos}}

\par
\vspace{1em}
\hspace*{160pt}\parbox{7.6cm}{{\large Geraldo Francisco Donega Zafalon}}

\par
\vfill
\begin{center}
\textbf{{\large São José do Rio Preto}\\
{\large 2021}}
\end{center}
\newpage


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\pagestyle{fancy}

\newpage

% Agradecimentos

% Espaçamento duplo

\noindent{\LARGE\textbf{Agradecimentos}}

\vspace{1cm}
\doublespacing
 


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\newpage
\doublespacing
\vspace*{10pt}
% Abstract
\begin{center}  \emph{\begin{large}Resumo\end{large}}\label{resumo}
\vspace{2pt}
\end{center}


% Criei a página do abstract na mão, por isso tem bem mais comandos do que o resumo acima, apesar de serem idênticas.
\vspace*{10pt}
% Abstract
\begin{center}
 
  \emph{\begin{large}Abstract\end{large}}\label{abstract}
\vspace{2pt}
\end{center}

% Selecionar a linguagem acerta os padrões de hifenação diferentes entre inglês e português
\selectlanguage{english}
\noindent


\vspace*{1.5pt}
% Voltando ao português...
\selectlanguage{brazilian}

\newpage

\renewcommand{\listfigurename}{Lista de Ilustrações}

\thispagestyle{empty}

\listoffigures

% Lista de tabelas
\listoftables

% Abreviações
% Para imprimir as abreviações siga as instruções em 
% http://code.google.com/p/mestre-em-latex/wiki/ListaDeAbreviaturas
\renewcommand{\nomname}{Lista de Abreviaturas e Siglas}

\printnomenclature

% Índice
%\addcontentsline{List of Tables}{List of Figures}
\tableofcontents
```

This is my `meta.tex`, to insert all the packages and commands in my document:

```
%%% Pacotes utilizados %%%
\usepackage{float}

%% Codificação e formatação básica do LaTeX
% Suporte para português (hifenação e caracteres especiais)
\usepackage[english,brazilian]{babel}

% Codificação do arquivo
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

% Mapear caracteres especiais no PDF
\usepackage{cmap}

% Codificação da fonte
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

% Essencial para colocar funções e outros símbolos matemáticos
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts,textcomp}

%% Layout
% Customização do layout da página, margens espelhadas
%\usepackage[twoside]{geometry}
\usepackage{geometry}
% Aumenta as margens internas para espiral
\geometry{bindingoffset=10pt,bmargin=30mm}
% Só pra ajustar o layout
\setlength{\marginparwidth}{90pt}
%\usepackage{layout}

% Para definir espaçamento entre as linhas
\usepackage{setspace}

% Espaçamento do texto para o frame
\setlength{\fboxsep}{1em}

% Faz com que as margens tenham o mesmo tamanho horizontalmente
%\geometry{hcentering}

%% Elementos Gráficos
% Para incluir figuras (pacote extendido)
\usepackage[]{graphicx}

% Suporte a cores
\usepackage{color}

% Criar figura dividida em subfiguras
\usepackage{subfig}
%\captionsetup[subfigure]{style=default, margin=0pt, parskip=0pt, hangindent=0pt, indention=0pt, singlelinecheck=true, labelformat=parens, labelsep=space}

% Caso queira guardar as figuras em uma pasta separada
% (descomente e) defina o caminho para o diretório:
\graphicspath{{./imgs/}}

% Customizar as legendas de figuras e tabelas
\usepackage{caption}

% Criar ambientes com 2 ou mais colunas
\usepackage{multicol}

% Ative o comando abaixo se quiser colocar figuras de fundo (e.g., capa)
%\usepackage{wallpaper}
% Exemplo para inserir a figura na capa está no arquivo pre.tex (linha 7)
% Ajuste da posição da figura no eixo Y
%\addtolength{\wpYoffset}{-140pt}
% Ajuste da posição da figura no eixo X
%\addtolength{\wpXoffset}{36pt}

%% Tabelas
% Elementos extras para formatação de tabelas
\usepackage{array}

% Tabelas com qualidade de publicação
\usepackage{booktabs}

% Para criar tabelas maiores que uma página
\usepackage{longtable}

% adicionar tabelas e figuras como landscape
\usepackage{lscape}


\usepackage{listings}
%% Lista de Abreviações
% Cria lista de abreviações
\usepackage[intoc,portuguese]{nomencl}
\renewcommand\nomname{Lista de Abreviações}
\makenomenclature

%% Notas de rodapé
% Lidar com notas de rodapé em diversas situações
\usepackage{footnote}

% Notas criadas nas tabelas ficam no fim das tabelas
\makesavenoteenv{tabular}

%% Links dinâmicos
% Suporte para hipertexto, links para referências e figuras
\usepackage{hyperref}
% Configurações dos links e metatags do PDF a ser gerado
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true, linkcolor=black, citecolor=black, filecolor=blue, urlcolor=black,
            pdfauthor={Sandro Gentil Bento de Azevedo},
            pdftitle={Formação de Equipes de Desenvolvimento de Software: A importância das \textit{Soft Skills}},
            pdfsubject={Assunto do Projeto},
            pdfkeywords={haplotipo, grafo, One-step},
            pdfproducer={Latex},
            pdfcreator={pdflatex}}

% Conta o número de páginas
\usepackage{lastpage}

%% Referências bibliográficas e afins
% Formatar as citações no texto e a lista de referências
\usepackage[alf,abnt-repeated-author-omit=no,abnt-title-command=yes,abnt-emphasize=bf,bibjustif,abnt-etal-list=0,abnt-etal-cite=3]{abntex2cite}

\usepackage{pdfpages}

% Adicionar bibliografia, índice e conteúdo na Tabela de conteúdo
% Não inclui lista de tabelas e figuras no índice
\usepackage{tocbibind}

%% Pontuação e unidades
% Posicionar inteligentemente a vírgula como separador decimal
\usepackage{icomma}

% Formatar as unidades com as distâncias corretas
\usepackage[tight]{units}
% \usepackage{nomencl}
%% Cabeçalho e rodapé
% Controlar os cabeçalhos e rodapés
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
% Usar os estilos do pacote fancyhdr
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{\fancyhf{}}
% Limpar os campos do cabeçalho atual
\fancyhead{}
% Número da página do lado esquerdo [L] nas páginas ímpares [O] e do lado direito [R] nas páginas pares [E]

\fancyhead[RO,R]{\thepage}

% Nome da seção do lado direito em páginas ímpares
\fancyhead[LO]{\nouppercase{\rightmark}}
% Nome do capítulo do lado esquerdo em páginas pares

\fancyhead[L]{\nouppercase{\leftmark}}

% Limpar os campos do rodapé
\fancyfoot{}
% Omitir linha de separação entre cabeçalho e conteúdo
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
% Omitir linha de separação entre rodapé e conteúdo
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
% Altura do cabeçalho
\headheight 14.6pt

%% Inserir comentários no texto
% Marcar mudanças e fazer comentários
%\usepackage[margins]{trackchanges}
% Iniciais do autor
%\renewcommand{\initialsTwo}{bcv}
% Notas na margem interna
%\reversemarginpar

%% Comandos customizados

% Espécie e abreviação
\newcommand{\subde}{\emph{Clypeaster subdepressus}}
\newcommand{\subsus}{\emph{C.~subdepressus}}

% Título do projeto

\newcommand{\titulo}{Formação de Equipes de Desenvolvimento de Software: A importância das \textit{Soft Skills}  }
\newcommand{\nomedoaluno}{Sandro Gentil Bento de Azevedo}

\usepackage{indentfirst}

\usepackage{url}
%% Pacotes não implementados
% Para não sobrar espaços em branco estranhos
%\widowpenalty=1000
%\clubpenalty=1000
```

The problem must be in some of those files.

Comment: Could you please provide a minimal working example so that we can see the relevant parts of your code, which create this behavior?

Comment: I believe this is the only command related to the problem itself. But I'm indeed using a meta.tex and pre.tex to help me out with the editions.

Comment: While in your document the `\tableofcontents` command is the only one responsible for the table of contents, it is not the only one related to the problem, as the answer might depend on the document class for example. This is why a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/201628) is _always_ relevant. I'm not sure how to solve your problem since I can't test any solution, but you might find an answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10943/201628).

Comment: This seems Brazilian, you guys tend to use a specific class based on memoir, try `\tableofcontents*`, if that does not work, provide code others can test

Comment: @Gunter added the code was missing

Comment: @Vincent added the code that was missing

Comment: @daleif provided the code

Comment: This is a lot of code (a lot of which is certainly irrelevant to your question), but there is still no document class, and it is certainly not a compilable document that others can test. Did you try daleif's suggestion? If it did not work, can you try to build a small document that others can compile and that reproduces the problem?

Comment: @Vincent my guess is that or the problem is there or there's a specif command that can help me out. I'm new using LaTeX and I got this tamplate from another student. I saw some other examples of  \tableofcontents online and I didn't see this problem at all. My document is divided in a bunch of files, but I'll try to create a document that others can test and post it here. Thank you anyway Vincent.

Comment: The code you provided is excessively large and incomplete, there is no document class.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because OP answered the question himself.

Comment: @close voters self-answering is not a reason for closure - it is surely a (multiple) duplicate but it's not otherwise unclear in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution for the problem.

I just added this package in my meta.tex and it worked.

`\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}`