# How to remove double "Contents" heading generated by memoir?

Tags: table-of-contents, memoir

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to remove the self-reference of the ToC from the ToC?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10943/how-to-remove-the-self-reference-of-the-toc-from-the-toc)

I am using `memoir` with the article setting. For some reason my table of contents has a double "Contents" heading:

[image: Screen shoot showing the double headings]

Why are there two, and how can I get just one?

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass[12pt, article]{memoir}
\usepackage{microtype}

\counterwithout{section}{chapter}
\setsecnumdepth{subsection}
\settocdepth{subsection}
\renewcommand*{\chaptitlefont}{\LARGE\centering}

\begin{document}
    \chapter*{My article}

    \begin{abstract}
        Lorem Ipsum\ldots
    \end{abstract}

    \pagestyle{plain}
    \tableofcontents
    \section{Introduction}
    \subsection{Subsection 1}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Read chapter 9 of the [`memoir`](http://ctan.org/pkg/memoir) manual. The commands `\tableofcontents`, `\listoffigures` and `\listoftables` have both non-starred and starred variants. Non-starred variants add their own titles to the ToC, the starred variants behave as in the standard document classes.

Comment: Ah, so that's what's going on. It is actually a part of the ToC! I first thought I was blind considering I had tried to read that chapter but I was trying to figure out why it had double header, not how to make it not add itself to the ToC, so that explains that! :)