# How to create my own list of things

Tags: table-of-contents

I’m writing a document in the latex and it contains some BNF grammar noations in several places of the documents. (I used verbatim package in order to write these BNF grammar notations)

Now I want to add a new section to the document that shows name of all grammar notation and their page numbers. This should be similar to “**List of Figures**” page.

I’m new to Latex and your help will be very helpful for me.

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the [`tocloft`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/tocloft/) package. For a short introduction see for example: http://texblog.org/2008/07/13/define-your-own-list-of/

Comment: If you need more specific advice, you should give a MWE. Otherwise "accepting" an answer is the proper way to show your content.

Answer (score 14):

Example for the `tocloft` package:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true}

\newcommand{\listexamplename}{List of mycustomfiction}
\newlistof{mycustomfiction}{mcf}{\listexamplename}

% Reset section numbering between unnumbered chapters
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/71162/reset-section-numbering-between
\newcommand{\mycustomfiction}[1]
{%
    \refstepcounter{mycustomfiction}
    \addcontentsline{mcf}{mycustomfiction}
    {\protect\numberline{\themycustomfiction}#1}\par
}

\begin{document}

    % How to remove double “Contents” heading generated by memoir?
    % https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47225/how-to-remove-double-contents-heading-generated-by-memoir
    \tableofcontents
    \newpage
    \listofmycustomfiction

    \chapter{Two mycustomfiction}
    \mycustomfiction{Your first example}
    \label{1st_ex}
    Your first example

    \mycustomfiction{Your second example}
    \label{2nd_ex}
    Your second example

    \chapter{One example}
    \mycustomfiction{Your third example. (See example \ref{1st_ex} and \ref{2nd_ex})}
    Your third example. (See example \ref{1st_ex} and \ref{2nd_ex})

\end{document}
```

[image]

For the memoir package you need to build more things using the `memoir`'s class emulation of `tocloft`. See the question 
 for `memoir`'s example: [Custom list throw LaTeX Error: Command \mycustomfiction already defined?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/388489/custom-list-throw-latex-error-command-mycustomfiction-already-defined)

Comment: I would like to format each entry in the "List of mycustomfiction" so that it follows this pattern "Figure 1.1 - Caption.......pagenumber" any thoughts on how to attack the issue?