# Restart section numbering after unnumbered chapter

Tags: sectioning, numbering

How can I make one chapter (Conclusion) without number?

I have tried this:

```
\documentclass{report}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{Introduction}
\chapter{Chapter 1}  
\chapter*{Conclusion} 
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Conclusion}  
\end{document}
```

I have this

[image]

But I want:

```
1  Conclusion
2  Perspectives
```

not

```
5  Conclusion
6  Perspectives
```

Comment: possible duplicate: [Reset section numbering between unnumbered chapters](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/71162/579).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`\chapter*` doesn't increment the `chapter` counter, which resets the section counter. It's easiest to just reset the `section` counter to 0:

```
\chapter*{Conclusion}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Conclusion}
\setcounter{section}{0}
```