# Fixing section numbers to alphabet letters with \theHsection

Tags: sectioning, hyperref, numbering

I researched, and I am having a similar trouble to this one:
[Reset section numbering between unnumbered chapters](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/71162/reset-section-numbering-between-unnumbered-chapters)

My problem is the following. I am using koma-script book class. I want to use `\chapter*` for Appendices, so that it doesn't say Chapter 7 after having six chapters. In particular, after the end of Chapter 6, I have the following.

```
\newpage
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Appendices}
\chapter*{Appendices}
\setcounter{section}{0}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Alph{section}}
\section{Title of appendix A}
\section{Title of appendix B}
\section{Title of appendix C}
```

Now, the above code allows me to put A, B, C for each appendix, but hyperref bookmarks are messed up (same as the issue of the link). So instead of

```
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Alph{section}}
```

I tried with

```
\renewcommand{\theHsection}{\Alph{section}}
```

This fixes hyperref links, but it puts 6.1, 6.2, 6.3 instead of A, B, C for each of my appendix. How can I use the alphabet instead of numbers together with `\theHsection`?

Edited:

Please look at the following code:

```
\documentclass[paper=letter, fontsize=11pt, chapterprefix=on, oneside]{scrbook}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\thechapter.\arabic{section}}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{First numbered chapter}
\section{AB}
\section{BC}
\section{DE}

\newpage
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Appendices}
\chapter*{Appendices}
\setcounter{section}{0}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Alph{section}}
\section{Title of appendix A}
\section{Title of appendix B}
\section{Title of appendix C}
\end{document}
```

With this, bookmarks of "Title of appendix A", for example, is at the wrong location. It refers to "1.1 AB" when I want it to refer to "A. Title of appendix A."

So I change `\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Alph{section}}` to `\renewcommand{\theHsection}{\Alph{section}}`. Then bookmarks are all correct, but it now puts "1.1 Title of appendix A."

Comment: You know that this difficult to answer, having no compilable document to work with.

Comment: I built a small document using your code and I have no problems with wrong bookmarks etc.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Thanks for looking in. Let me edit the question with a little more details.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that after the section values occur again and the current chapter value is still `1` (in this document version here).

This confuses `hyperref`, since it uses again `section.` as prefix for the anchors. Changing `\theHsection` to apply another `prefix`, say `appendixsection.` cures the problem.

```
\documentclass[paper=letter, fontsize=11pt, chapterprefix=on, oneside]{scrbook}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\thechapter.\arabic{section}}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{First numbered chapter}
\section{AB}
\section{BC}
\section{DE}

\newpage
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Appendices}
\chapter*{Appendices}
\setcounter{section}{0}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Alph{section}}
\renewcommand{\theHsection}{appendixsection.\Alph{section}}
\section{Title of appendix A}
\blindtext[5]
\section{Title of appendix B}
\blindtext[5]
\section{Title of appendix C}
\blindtext[5]
\end{document}
```

Comment: I copied and complied your code. Although hyperref bookmarks are working great, somehow, it still says "1.1 Title of Appendix A", not "A. Title of Appendix A."

Comment: @BzTAK178: See the edit please

Comment: That fixed it. Thank you very much for your time and help.

Comment: @BzTAK178: Thanks too. Happy TeXing!

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Thank you Christian. You saved my day.

Comment: @Sveinung: Well, it's all-a-days-work for ... a user of TeX.SX ;-) Happy TeXing too ;-)