# Producing accurate hyperlinks in partial grade tables for (customized) numbered questions (exam)

Tags: tables, hyperref, cross-referencing, counters, exam

**Question:** Is there a way to customize the question numbering for questions within your own "grade range" using the `exam` document class and maintain the integrity of the question hyperlinks in `\partialgradetable`?

**Edit:** I just added the line `\renewcommand*{\thequestion}{\the\value{question}}` after `\setcounter{question}{0}` trying to follow an approach outlined in [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/71162/reset-section-numbering-between-unnumbered-chapters). But I still have the same issue.

---

The code

```
\documentclass[addpoints]{exam}
\usepackage[
colorlinks=true,
linkcolor=blue]{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\begin{questions}
\begingradingrange{range1}
\question A question.
\question Another questions. 
\question Yet another question.
\endgradingrange{range1}

\setcounter{question}{0}
\renewcommand*{\thequestion}{\the\value{question}}

\begingradingrange{range2}
\question A second question. 
\question Another second question.
\endgradingrange{range2}

\end{questions}

\partialgradetable{range1}

\partialgradetable{range2}

\end{document}
```

produces the following:

[image]

As can be seen, the question counter resets properly, but the hyperlink capability in the tables is destroyed. Even though the third question in `range1` shows `??` in the table, if you click on the `3`, then you are taken to the third question as you should be; however, if you click on the `1` or `2` in either table, then you are taken to the first or second question in `range2`, respectively.

Is there a way to set the counter to maintain the integrity of the question hyperlinks in the partial grade tables? That is, clicking on the `1,2,3` in the first table should take me to those questions in `range1` while clicking on `1,2` in the second table should take me to those questions in `range2`. Of course, I'd like to also be able to set the counter to something not necessarily `0` or `1` and still have it work properly. Any ideas?

Comment: You are not just confusing hyperref.  The range itself is defined by the question numbers used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will display the numbers desired.  I can't guarantee it will work correctly.

```
\documentclass[addpoints]{exam}
\usepackage[
colorlinks=true,
linkcolor=blue]{hyperref}

\newcounter{myquestion}
\renewcommand{\thequestion}{\arabic{myquestion}}

\begin{document}

\begin{questions}
\begingradingrange{range1}
\stepcounter{myquestion}%
\question A question.
\stepcounter{myquestion}%
\question Another questions. 
\stepcounter{myquestion}%
\question Yet another question.
\endgradingrange{range1}

\setcounter{myquestion}{0}

\begingradingrange{range2}
\stepcounter{myquestion}%
\question A second question.
\stepcounter{myquestion}%
\question Another second question.
\endgradingrange{range2}

\end{questions}

\partialgradetable{range1}

\partialgradetable{range2}

\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

---

Revised solution incorporating `\stepcounter{myquestion}` into `\question`.  Note, `\question` is local to the `questions` environment.

```
\documentclass[addpoints]{exam}
\usepackage[
colorlinks=true,
linkcolor=blue]{hyperref}

\newcounter{myquestion}
\renewcommand{\thequestion}{\arabic{myquestion}}

\begin{document}

\begin{questions}
\let\oldquestion=\question
\renewcommand{\question}{\stepcounter{myquestion}\oldquestion}
\begingradingrange{range1}
\question A question.
\question Another questions. 
\question Yet another question.
\endgradingrange{range1}

\setcounter{myquestion}{0}

\begingradingrange{range2}
\question A second question.
\question Another second question.
\endgradingrange{range2}

\end{questions}

\partialgradetable{range1}

\partialgradetable{range2}

\end{document}
```

Comment: From what I can tell, it seems to work! Since I will be creating numerous questions and several partial grade tables, is there any way to automate the use of `\stepcounter{myquestion}` as you have used it in your solution (I could manually do it, of course, but that will get tiresome rather quickly)?

Comment: The second solution redefines \question to do that.

Comment: This is fantastic! Thanks so much--fiddling with `exam` has really motivated me to learn more about the innards of TeX...someday maybe I too can be a wizard. Thanks again. Cheers. `:-)`

Comment: I've toyed with the idea of writing a book titled "Secrets of the LaTeX Illuminati",

Comment: If you ever decide to write it, let me know--I'll gladly be a reader.