# Reset numeration in sections/subsections in each chapter

Tags: sectioning, chapters, amsbook

I'm making some un-numbered chapters for my thesis but I'm adding numerated sections. The thing is that the enumeration doesn't reset when I add a new chapter, so I have

Chapter 1 > Section 1 - Section 2

Chapter 2 > Section 3 - Section 4

Instead of

Chapter 1 > Section 1 - Section 2

Chapter 2 > Section 1 - Section 2

This is a MWE, because I'm running fancyhdr and Creff, but I guess this does the work well enough portraying my problem

```
\documentclass[oneside]{amsbook}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{manfnt}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{latexsym,mathrsfs}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amsfonts,amssymb,enumerate}

\begin{document}
\chapter*{Ch 1}
\input{chapters/ch1}
\chapter*{Ch 2}
\input{chapters/ch2}
\end{document}
```

Where each "ch" looks like this:

```
\section{Sec 1}
\subsection{Subsec 1}
\begin{theorem} \label{thmc1}
Thm
\end{theorem}

\section{Sec 2}
\subsection{Subsec 2}
\begin{theorem} \label{thmc2}
Thm
\end{theorem}
```

I'll add an image to make it easier to visualize:

[image]
[image]

What I'm looking for is a way to reset the numeration of each section and subsection, etc. in each chapter, so it says 1. Sec 1 - 1.1 Subsec 1 in chapter 2, etc.

Thanks!

Comment: How should cross references look like? Something like "see Section 1" is ambiguous if you restart the section numbering inside of each unnumbered chapter.

Comment: by adding an hyperlink to said theorem and clarifying, just in case, in which chapter it is, say something like "in Chapter 4, look at [theorem 1.1.3]", besides, in these unnumbered chapters I don't think I'll put many cross references outside the same chapter.

Comment: You can use `\setcounter{section}{0}` to restart the section counter. Since you mentioned  hyperlinks, the following question might also be interesting: [Reset section numbering between unnumbered chapters](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/71162/134144)

Answer (score 1):

For working with `hyperref`, I suggest the following strategy.

```
\documentclass[oneside]{amsbook}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{manfnt}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amsfonts,amssymb,enumerate}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]

\newcounter{fakechapter}
\newcommand{\unchapter}[1]{%
  \chapter*{#1}%
  \stepcounter{fakechapter}%
  \setcounter{section}{0}%
}
\renewcommand{\theHsection}{F\thefakechapter.\arabic{section}}
\newcommand{\normalchapters}{%
  \renewcommand{\thesection}{\thechapter.\arabic{section}}%
  \renewcommand{\theHsection}{\thechapter.\arabic{section}}%
}  

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\unchapter{Ch 1}

\section{Sec 1}
\subsection{Subsec 1}
\begin{theorem} \label{thmc1-A}
Thm
\end{theorem}

\section{Sec 2}
\subsection{Subsec 2}
\begin{theorem} \label{thmc2-A}
Thm
\end{theorem}

\unchapter{Ch 2}
\section{Sec 1}
\subsection{Subsec 1}
\begin{theorem} \label{thmc1-B}
Thm
\end{theorem}

\section{Sec 2}
\subsection{Subsec 2}
\begin{theorem} \label{thmc2-B}
Thm
\end{theorem}

\normalchapters

\chapter{Normal}
\section{Sec 1}
\subsection{Subsec 1}
\begin{theorem} \label{thmc1-C}
Thm
\end{theorem}

\section{Sec 2}
\subsection{Subsec 2}
\begin{theorem} \label{thmc2-C}
Thm
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

I removed `latexsym` that should not be used along with `amssymb` (and generally to be avoided anyway).

Remember to issue `\normalchapters` when you start with numbered chapters.