# A list of all the labelled sentences

Tags: table-of-contents, cross-referencing, environments

I keep adding a class of sentences in different areas of my tex:

```
\section{...}
... 
sentence1
... 
\subsection{...}
... 
sentence2
... 
\section{...}
... 
sentence3
...
```

I would like to make a `add` mechanisms, label all the sentences and later summarize them in a place by `listallthesentences`:

```
\section{...}
... 
\add{sentence1}
... 
\subsection{...}
... 
\add{sentence2}
... 
\section{...}
... 
\add{sentence3}
... 
\section{summary}
\listallthesentences
```

In the summary, it will be better, if all the sentences are repeated and have a reference pointed to their initial place.

Does anyone know how to realize this?

Comment: This is too vague; what would you list in the "List of all sentences"?

Comment: Just repeat the sentences which are labelled with `add`, and have a reference pointed to their initial place...

Comment: Use the package `tocloft`, see also http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/61086/how-to-create-my-own-list-of-things.

Comment: In my answer below I provided a solution for generating the list; it's not clear, however, what you mean with "labelled sentences". Could you please ellaborate a little more about this labelling?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `\@starttoc` to generate a list similar to the ToC, Lof or LoT (it's not clear from the description, however, what "labelled sentence" means):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\listofsentences{\@starttoc{los}}
\newcommand\addsentence[1]{%
\par\csname phantomsection\endcsname\addcontentsline{los}{section}{#1}#1\par}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{Test Section One}
\addsentence{This is a test sentence.}
\section{Test Section Two}
\addsentence{This is another test sentence.}

\section{Summary}
\listofsentences

\end{document}
```

[image]

A variant (requested in a comment) without page numbers and with normal font for the entries in the new list:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\newcounter{sentence}
\newcommand\listofsentences{\@starttoc{los}}
\newcommand\addsentence[1]{%
\stepcounter{sentence}%
\par\csname phantomsection\endcsname\addcontentsline{los}{sentence}{#1}#1\par}
\newcommand\l@sentence[2]{\par\noindent#1}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{Test Section One}
\addsentence{This is a test sentence.}
\section{Test Section Two}
\addsentence{This is another test sentence.}

\section{Summary}
\listofsentences

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your comment, it is quite what I need... By the way, in the summary, I don't want to show the page of the sentences, also I don't want to make them bold, could you adjust your response?

Comment: @SoftTimur sure! I've updated my answer. Is it something like that what you need?