# Define a command printing later given texts

Tags: macros

I define a new command taking an arguments, e.g., `\mycmd{some text here}`.

This command is used many times in the documents like:

```
\documentclass{a-latex-class}

\begin{document}

\mycmd{text number 1}
\mycmd{text number 2}
\mycmd{text number 3}
\end{document}
```

Here is my question.
How do I define another command, `\whatiwant`, that print all of texts given as arguments in `\mycmd`?

Moreover, I expect to use the command `\whatiwant` before using of any `\mycmd`, for example:

```
\documentclass{a-latex-class}

\begin{document}
\whatiwant
\mycmd{text number 1}
\mycmd{text number 2}
\mycmd{text number 3}
\end{document}
```

What I have try is using a temporary/auxiliary file storing the texts I want. However, it seems that I need to typeset the document before using the temporary file which is not convenient to do in that way.

Comment: You could define your own ToC https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/61086/how-to-create-my-own-list-of-things and then add to it your text with ` \addcontentsline`.

Comment: You won't get around using an auxiliary file and compile at least twice. TeX typesets a page, ships it out (i.e. appends it to the output file) and then forgets it. After that, it is impossible to change the page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a ToC-like interface, making `\whatiwant` act similar to `\tableofcontents`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\whatiwant}{\@starttoc{wiw}}
\newcommand{\l@whatiwant}[2]{#1\par}
\newcommand{\mycmd}[1]{\addcontentsline{wiw}{whatiwant}{#1}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

Lorem ipsum 1 \ldots

\whatiwant

Lorem ipsum 2 \ldots

\mycmd{text number 1}
\mycmd{text number 2}
\mycmd{text number 3}

Lorem ipsum 3 \ldots

\whatiwant% Doesn't print anything

\end{document}
```

Note that a ToC-like interface generally is used only once. As such, `\whatiwant` only prints its contents once, but this could be changed.

Since it is a ToC-like setup, you will only see changes after the second compilation.