# Table of Contents for arbitrary objects

Tags: table-of-contents, titletoc, etoc

I am working on a document that contains a large amount of content of different type, that needs to be listed in several tables of contents.

**e.g.**

```
Contents
Chapter 1........................1
  Section 1.1....................1
  Section 1.2....................2
Chapter 2.......................14

List of Figures
Figure 1.........................7
Figure 2........................15

List of Tables
Table 1..........................4
Table 5..........................8

List of ItemTypeA
Group I
  ItemTypeA Description............3
  ItemTypeA Description...........14
Group II
  ItemTypeA Description............5
  ItemTypeA Description...........52

Lit of ItemTypeB
Group I
  ItemTypeB Description............7
  ItemTypeB Description...........11
  ItemTypeB Description...........21
```

One can use the commands

```
\tableofcontents

\listoffigures

\listoftables
```

to generate the first three tables of contents automatically.

- How can I wrap an object (e.g. `\lipsum` or several paragraphs of content) of type `ItemType` as a single unit and add it to a personalized table of contents?
- How can I display such table of contents?

---

**EDIT:** my question is different from [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/388535/134144) because i need to support some level of nesting within each custom table of contents.

Comment: Probably https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/388535/134144 can help.

Comment: You could create a new float type using the newfloat package.  This will provide a \listof...  OTOH, you need to replace \caption with \addcontentsline and/or \addtocontents with the new filename.  The trick is to look at the AUX to see how normal \captions are formatted.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `tocloft` package. The documentation (`texdoc tocloft`) section **2.4 New list of...** describes how to create new contents-like lists, how to format the entries, and how to flag the entries in the document. Several examples are given.

Comment: Thank you for your input. `tocloft` is close, but not quite like, the desired functionality; the main difference is that `tocloft` *apparently* groups/counts entries based on the document structure (chapters, sections, etc.), whereas the question asks for customized grouping. One option could be to use a separate command `listof` for each grouping and then change the textsize/font of the command `\listofgroup`. But that's outside my grasp at this moment.

Comment: The ToC, LoF, LoT, and any other listof commands work by the appropriate elements in the document (chapters, sections, captions,etc) writing their data to the `.aux` file and on the next LaTeX run the ToC etc read the data from the `.aux` file and print it. If you want your listof to do sorting, as you imply, then I think that you will have to develop a lot of new code for that. Think about what you can do within the document structure itself. Sections are subservient to chapters; can you make similar constructs for your "ItemType..."/"Group..." elements?