Define your own “list of …”
I'm currently working on a book, and I want to create a list of examples. I tried lots of solutions available online, but none suited me well - see for example:
https://texblog.org/2008/07/13/define-your-own-list-of/#comments
My book is written in Arabic. Here is my MWE.
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,openany]{book}

‎\usepackage{polyglossia}‎‎

‎\usepackage[top=2cm,bottom=2cm‎,
‎left=3cm,right=2cm,headheight=17pt,includehead‎,
‎includefoot,heightrounded]{geometry}‎ 

‎\usepackage{fancyhdr}‎

‎\pagestyle{fancy}‎

‎\fancyhf{}‎ 

‎\fancyhead[RE,LO]{\thepage}‎

‎\fancyhead[LE]{\small\leftmark}‎

‎\fancyhead[RO]{\small\rightmark}‎‎

‎\usepackage{natbib}‎

‎\RequirePackage[linkcolor=black,bookmarksnumbered,pagebackref=true]{hyperref}‎‎

‎\hypersetup{colorlinks,citecolor=purple,linkcolor=blue}‎

‎\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}‎‎‎‎

‎\usepackage{amsthm}‎‎

‎\usepackage{dingbat}%  for typing pencil with‎: ‎\smallpencil‎

‎\theoremstyle{definition} 

‎\newtheorem{definition}{تعریف}[chapter]‎

‎\newtheorem{example}[definition]{\smallpencil‎ مثال} ‎‎

‎\setmainlanguage{arabic}‎‎

‎\setotherlanguage{english}‎‎

‎\setmainfont[Scale=1.2]{Arial}%{Amiri}%{Traditional Arabic}‎‎

‎\begin{document}‎‎

جميع حقوق النشر والنسخ، التصوير الليزري، الترجمة، الاقتباس و ... من هذا الكتاب محفوظة‏. إن نقل واقتباس الموضوعات مع الإرجاع لهذا الكتاب مسموح وبلا مانع.‎

‎\tableofcontents\addtocontents{toc}{\linespread{1.25}\selectfont}%to change line spacing in table of contents‎ 

‎\chapter{‏الفصل الأول}‎‎‎

\section{‎‏الاختبار الأول}

‎‏نص‎‎ ما أول

\section{‎‏الاختبار الثاني}

‎‏نص‎‎ ما ثاني

‎\chapter{‏الفصل الثاني}‎‎‎

\section{‎‏الاختبار الأول}

‎‏نص‎‎ ما أول

\section{‎‏الاختبار الثاني}

‏ ‎ما ثاني‎ نص‎‎ 

\begin{example}

‏ن‏ إنجاز الاختبار‎ ‎‎$‎H_0:\beta_1=0‎$‎‏‎ مقابل ‎$‎H_1:\beta_1\neq0‎$‎‏ عند المستوى ‎$‎‎\alpha‎=0.05‎$‎‏‎‏ باعتماد الإحصاء ‎‎‎‎يتم كما يلي

‎\end‎{example}‎

‎\end{document}

As I was advised by @mbert comments I edited the question a little bit.
The final code I tried is this:
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,openany]{book}

‎\usepackage{polyglossia}‎‎

‎\usepackage[top=2cm,bottom=2cm‎,
‎left=3cm,right=2cm,headheight=17pt,includehead‎,
‎includefoot,heightrounded]{geometry}‎ 

‎\usepackage{fancyhdr}‎

‎\pagestyle{fancy}‎

‎\fancyhf{}‎ 

‎\fancyhead[RE,LO]{\thepage}‎

‎\fancyhead[LE]{\small\leftmark}‎

‎\fancyhead[RO]{\small\rightmark}‎‎

‎\usepackage{natbib}‎

‎\RequirePackage[linkcolor=black,bookmarksnumbered,pagebackref=true]{hyperref}‎‎

‎\hypersetup{colorlinks,citecolor=purple,linkcolor=blue}‎

‎\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}‎‎‎‎

‎\usepackage{amsthm}‎‎

‎\usepackage{dingbat}%  for typing pencil with‎: ‎\smallpencil‎

‎\theoremstyle{definition} 

‎\newtheorem{definition}{تعریف}[chapter]‎

\newtheorem{example}[definition]{\smallpencil‎ مثال} ‎‎
\usepackage{thmtools}
\declaretheorem[name=مثال]{example}
\renewcommand{\listoftheoremname}{‏قائمة الأمثلة}%the Arabic of List of ‎examples‎

‎\setmainlanguage{arabic}‎‎

‎\setotherlanguage{english}‎‎

‎\setmainfont[Scale=1.2]{Arial}%{Amiri}%{Traditional Arabic}‎‎

‎\begin{document}‎‎

جميع حقوق النشر والنسخ، التصوير الليزري، الترجمة، الاقتباس و ... من هذا الكتاب محفوظة‏. إن نقل واقتباس الموضوعات مع الإرجاع لهذا الكتاب مسموح وبلا مانع.‎

‎\tableofcontents\addtocontents{toc}{\linespread{1.25}\selectfont}%to change line spacing in table of contents‎ 

\begingroup
\let\footnotemark\relax
\listoftheorems[ignoreall,show={example}]
\endgroup

‎\chapter{‏الفصل الأول}‎‎‎

\section{‎‏الاختبار الأول}

‎‏نص‎‎ ما أول

\section{‎‏الاختبار الثاني}

‎‏نص‎‎ ما ثاني

‎\chapter{‏الفصل الثاني}‎‎‎

\section{‎‏الاختبار الأول}

‎‏نص‎‎ ما أول

\section{‎‏الاختبار الثاني}

‏ ‎ما ثاني‎ نص‎‎ 

\begin{example}

‏ن‏ إنجاز الاختبار‎ ‎‎$‎H_0:\beta_1=0‎$‎‏‎ مقابل ‎$‎H_1:\beta_1\neq0‎$‎‏ عند المستوى ‎$‎‎\alpha‎=0.05‎$‎‏‎‏ باعتماد الإحصاء ‎‎‎‎يتم كما يلي

‎\end‎{example}‎

‎\end{document}

I got two errors and one problem. The first error says  "LaTeX Error: Command \example already defined", but I need this
" \newtheorem{example}[definition]{\smallpencil‎ مثال} ‎‎"
to get section and chapter with small pencil‎ shape. The second error says " LaTeX Error: \listoftheoremname undefined."
Now, concerning the resulted problem, the result is good as it prints chapter and section of examples, but the title is in English "List of theorems", instead of Arabic.
So, I re-frame my question. I need three things:
1- using \begin{example} ... \end{example}, which is also in the referenced link given by by @mbert.
2- I need to print the small pencil shape, and to print the Arabic title instead of "List of ‎Theorems" .



I'd like to keep using: \begin{example} ... \end{example}

Welcome! Does https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/388535/ help? Off-topic: you are loading hyperref too late. Can you use a font everyone has? Arial is proprietary. A font from TeX Live is generally ideal.

See thmtools' \listoftheorems command. You can give it the options ignoreall,show=example to list only examples

@cfr Thanks for editing my question. Unfortunately,  in the referenced link you posted they use  \mycustomfiction{Your first example} to define new example. I really would like to keep using \begin{example} ... \end{example} environment. Also, I like to use \smallpencil‎ command. Concerning the Arabic font, could you use Amiri font or other Arabic font? Thanks for your contribution.

@mbert Thank you. In fact, I used that solution before, and it is not what I'm looking for.

@shahroor You should add to your question why that's not what you're looking for

@mbert The fundamental reason is I could not apply that solution with the possibility of changing the word "example" to its Arabic counterpart "مثال". The second reason is I'd like to maintain the \begin{example} ... \end{example} environment. I have so many environments in my original Tex file. For example, ‎\newtheorem{theorem}[definition]{مبرهنة}‎    ;
‎\newtheorem{talik}[definition]{تعليق}‎.

@shahroor I'm not sure what you mean, using \listoftheorems would not require you to change your example environment. Please add to the question what you've tried and why it did not work

The code you've provided is filled with invisible characters which cause fatal errors when attempting compilation. Please fix it.

I removed dozens, but some are enmeshed in the Arabic and I'm not going to waste any more time trying to find them, since I've not even got to \begin{document} despite commenting half the preamble.

@cfr Thank you for the editing, and I really appreciate your time and efforts.

Perhaps using \@starttoc command, and the titletoc and titlesec packages to assist with formatting.
screenshot of output

the code
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\hypersetup{
  colorlinks=true,
  linkcolor=blue,
}

\contentsuse{shatitle}{new}
% toc settings
\titleclass{\shatitle}{straight}[\section]
\titleformat{\shatitle}{}{}{}{}
\titlecontents{shatitle}% <paragraph>
[1cm]% <left>
{\small\itshape}% <above-code>
{}% <numbered-entry-format>; you could also use {\thecontentslabel. } to show the numbers
{}% <numberless-entry-format>
{\titlerule*[0.5em]{$\cdot$}\contentspage}

\newcounter{example}
\newenvironment{example}[1][]{%
  \refstepcounter{example}%
  \addcontentsline{new}{shatitle}{example \theexample: #1}%
  \textbf{Example \theexample~#1 }}{}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\mylistofexamples}{\section*{my list of examples}\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}\@starttoc{new}}

\begin{document}
\mylistofexamples
\begin{example}[optional title]
  \lipsum[1]
\end{example}

\begin{example}[another arg]
  \lipsum[2]
\end{example}
\end{document}

example numbers within chapters
following the comment, you can use
\renewcommand{\theexample}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{example}}

as in the following
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\hypersetup{
  colorlinks=true,
  linkcolor=blue,
}

\contentsuse{shatitle}{new}
% toc settings
\titleclass{\shatitle}{straight}[\section]
\titleformat{\shatitle}{}{}{}{}
\titlecontents{shatitle}% <paragraph>
[1cm]% <left>
{\small\itshape}% <above-code>
{}% <numbered-entry-format>; you could also use {\thecontentslabel. } to show the numbers
{}% <numberless-entry-format>
{\titlerule*[0.5em]{$\cdot$}\contentspage}

\newcounter{example}
\renewcommand{\theexample}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{example}}
\newenvironment{example}[1][]{%
  \refstepcounter{example}%
  \addcontentsline{new}{shatitle}{example \theexample: #1}%
  \textbf{Example \theexample~#1 }}{}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\mylistofexamples}{\section*{my list of examples}\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}\@starttoc{new}}

\begin{document}
\mylistofexamples
\chapter{my first chapter}
\begin{example}[optional title]
  \lipsum[1]
\end{example}

\begin{example}[another arg]
  \lipsum[2]
\end{example}
\end{document}


Thank you so much. Since I'm writing a book, I need to make the examples counter like this: example 23.2, means it is the item number 23 in chapter two. What changes should I make in your code, sir?

@shahroor see the update

So much appreciated. Your code works very well without any errors. I just needed to remove "\itshape" command from {\small\itshape}, because the Arabic font doesn't work properly with an italic shape.
One last thing, in your code you used \section*{my list of examples}. Could we use something that helps making "my list of examples" appears in the page header? Thank you so much. I wouldn't have gotten this far without your help and time.
