Conclusion counting and listing
Throughout the document conclusions are made and need to be labelled sequentially:
[C-1 My first conclusion]
[C-2 My second conclusion]

Then at the end of the document, I want to list all the conclusions in order.
Currently I have this
% Define a new counter for conclusions
\newcounter{conclusioncounter}
\renewcommand{\theconclusioncounter}{C-\arabic{conclusioncounter}}

% Define a command to record and display conclusions
\newcommand{\conclusion}[1]{%
    \refstepcounter{conclusioncounter}% Increment counter
    \textbf{[\theconclusioncounter]} #1\label{conclusion:\theconclusioncounter}%
    % Add the conclusion to the list
    \gappto{\conclusionlist}{\noindent\textbf{[\theconclusioncounter]} #1\par}
}

% Command to display all conclusions at the end
\newcommand{\listconclusions}{%
    \section*{List of Conclusions}
    \conclusionlist % Print stored conclusions
}

that works for labelling the conclusions as I go through the document but when I come to list them at the end, they all get given the same (highest) number, I assuming as it is just referencing the variable that was last set. Therefore I guess, I am looking for a way to save the state of the variable at the creation of each conclusion?
[C-2 My first conclusion]
[C-2 My second conclusion]

Thanks

One way would be to implement it similar to the List of Figures, List of Tables etc, see for example https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/61086/how-to-create-my-own-list-of-things.

You can create a simple version of \gappto that expands the counter on definition, by making a copy of the previous list with \let and then \xdef the new command as the copy of the old one plus the new content. \xdef means "expanded global", as a combination of \edef (expanded, not global) and \gdef (global, not expanded), as follows:
\let\tmpconclusions\conclusionlist
\xdef\conclusionlist{\tmpconclusions\noindent{[\theconclusioncounter]} #1\par}%

Note that the definition above does not use \textbf. For some reason this requires the definition to be protected, in this case using \protected@xdef.
Full MWE:
\documentclass{article}


% Define a new counter for conclusions
\newcounter{conclusioncounter}
\renewcommand{\theconclusioncounter}{C-\arabic{conclusioncounter}}
\def\conclusionlist{}
% Define a command to record and display conclusions
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\conclusion}[1]{%
    \refstepcounter{conclusioncounter}% Increment counter
    \textbf{[\theconclusioncounter]} #1\label{conclusion:\theconclusioncounter}%
    \let\tmpconclusions\conclusionlist%
    \protected@xdef\conclusionlist{\tmpconclusions\noindent\textbf{[\theconclusioncounter]} #1\par}%
}
\makeatother

% Command to display all conclusions at the end
\newcommand{\listconclusions}{%
    \section*{List of Conclusions}
    \conclusionlist % Print stored conclusions
}
\begin{document}
This is my first conclusion: \conclusion{My first conclusion}. This is my second conclusion: \conclusion{My second conclusion}.

\listconclusions
\end{document}

Result:


That's great, thank you
