# How to remove "Contents" line from table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents, memoir

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Hiding the “Table of Contents” page from Table of Contents](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3879/hiding-the-table-of-contents-page-from-table-of-contents)
>   [How to remove the self-reference of the ToC from the ToC?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10943/how-to-remove-the-self-reference-of-the-toc-from-the-toc)

I have a table of contents in my `memoir` book.  I want there to be one line for each chapter, in addition to headings for each set of similar chapters.

For some reason, the `Contents` page is including the line "Contents" with page number "i".  How do I remove this useless line from the table of contents?

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\tableofcontents

\mainmatter

\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{Topic 1}

\chapter{Chapter 1}

This is the first chapter.

\chapter{Chapter 2}

This is the second chapter.

\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{Topic 2}

\chapter{Chapter 3}

This is the third chapter.

\chapter{Chapter 4}

This is the fourth chapter.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hiding the “Table of Contents” page from Table of
Contents (3879)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3879/) (the first instance I
think), and of [How to remove the self-reference of the ToC from the
ToC? (10943)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10943/) and
[How to remove double “Contents” heading generated by memoir?
(47225)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47225).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Replace `\tableofcontents` by

```
\begin{KeepFromToc}
  \tableofcontents
\end{KeepFromToc}
```

Answer (score 22):

To prevent adding the title to the ToC, use the starred version

```
\tableofcontents*
```