# Suppress/remove sectioning (heading) from table of contents?

Tags: sectioning, table-of-contents, page-breaking, vertical-alignment

(*NB: **not** the same question as [How to remove “Contents” line from table of contents [closed]](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/50031/how-to-remove-contents-line-from-table-of-contents)*)

Please consider the following MWE, compiled with `pdflatex test.tex`:

```
\documentclass[twoside,a4paper]{book}

\begin{document}

\section{TOC}

\tableofcontents

\cleardoublepage

\section{Sect 1}

\section{Sect 2}

\section{Sect 3}

\end{document}
```

This gives me:

- pg 1: "0.1 TOC" heading
- pg 2: blank
- pg 3: "Contents" heading (+ toc)
- pg 4: blank
- pg 5: "0.2 Sect 1"; "0.3 Sect 2" and "0.4 Sect 3" (as expected)

Now, what I would like to do, is have the heading for the table of contents set by a `\section` command (the `\section{TOC}`) - and I'd like the contents table to continue as a paragraph would continue after a `\section`; or - my expected result would be:

- pg 1: "0.1 TOC" heading (+ toc)
- pg 2: blank
- pg 3: "0.2 Sect 1"; "0.3 Sect 2" and "0.4 Sect 3" (as expected)

Obviously, in the example above, the `\tableofcontents` command first clears a double page - then inserts its own heading.

In other words, I'd like to suppress this heading inserted by `\tableofcontents` - however, *not* merely by `\renewcommand\contentsname{}`; because I'd also like to reclaim the vertical space that the toc heading usually claims (because it's actually a `\chapter`, I guess). How do I do that?

Answer (score 6):

OK, I think I got it, thanks to answer [#47241 How to remove the self-reference of the ToC from the ToC?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/47241/2595):

> ... found that I can simply not use \tableofcontents, and instead use:
>
> ```
> \makeatletter
> \@starttoc{toc}
> \makeatother
> ```
>
> This doesn't create a section for the table of contents, so the problem goes away.

And indeed, seems to work for above MWE too:

```
\documentclass[twoside,a4paper]{book}

\begin{document}

\section{TOC}

% \tableofcontents
\makeatletter
\@starttoc{toc}
\makeatother

\cleardoublepage

\section{Sect 1}

\section{Sect 2}

\section{Sect 3}

\end{document}
```

Hope this is the way to do this `:)` Cheers!

Comment: if that works, go with it.  i would probably have just used `\renewcommand{\tableofcontents}` and substituted the definition from `article.cls`, which uses `\section*` and also "does the right thing" for running heads .  (comparing the code for `\tableofcontents` in `book.cls` and `article.cls` would be instructive though; even better, look at the file from which the class files were generated (`classes.dtx` in the `source/latex/base` branch of the tex live tree) where there are some comments about how the code is constructed.)