# How to remove double “Contents” heading?

Tags: table-of-contents, tocbibind

How to remove double “Contents” heading generated by `book` class?

I've tried using the following advice which was given for the `memoir` class but none of these solve my problem.

[How to remove the self-reference of the ToC from the ToC?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10943/how-to-remove-the-self-reference-of-the-toc-from-the-toc)

[How to remove "Contents" line from table of contents](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/50031/how-to-remove-contents-line-from-table-of-contents)

[How to remove double "Contents" heading generated by memoir?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47225/how-to-remove-double-contents-heading-generated-by-memoir)

[Hiding the "Table of Contents" page from Table of Contents](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3879/hiding-the-table-of-contents-page-from-table-of-contents)

The structure of my document is as follows:

```
\documentclass[12pt, twoside, a4paper]{book}

\usepackage{tocbibind}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}
\tableofcontents

\mainmatter
\chapter[Chapter 1]{Chapter 1}

\appendix
\chapter[Appendix 1]{Appendix 1}

\backmatter
\cleardoublepage
\phantomsection
\clearpage

\begin{thebibliography}{}
\end{thebibliography}

%\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\numberline{}Bibliography}%
\chapter[Summary]{Summary}

\end{document}
```

I could solve the self reference 'contents' in the TOC by:

Removing the "%" in front of

```
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\numberline{}Bibliography}
```

and removing

```
\usepackage{tocbibind} 
\phantomsection
```

However, this creates a new problem. In that case the bibliography is no longer lined out with the backmatter (in ToC). In stead it is spaced with the titles of the Appendices (without the appendix number).

What I want is for the bibliography to appear inline with the backmatter sections (Summary) in the ToC without a self reference of the 'contents' heading.

Comment: Please edit your question and add a short example code that reproduces the problem.

Comment: I'm afraid I still can't reproduce the problem. It's best to provide a self-contained example (i.e. no `\include` or `\bibliography` commands, etc.).

Comment: Please have a look at [some points about minimal working examples (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) and reduce your code. Right now, it contains many many lines that don't have anything to do with your problem. Please also include how the solutions to the other questions didn't solve your problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have found a solution thanks to the information in:

[Making the bibliography appear in the table of contents](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8458/making-the-bibliography-appear-in-the-table-of-contents?rq=1)

In which the following answer helped me

https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/8459/16059

The trick was to replace

```
\usepackage{tocbibind}
```

With

```
\usepackage[nottoc,numbib]{tocbibind}
```

According to the post this should work for all standard classes (`article`, `book`, `report`).

Comment: I'm using the `\documentclass{report}` , and this method doesn't seem to work, because adding `nottoc`  , while it removes the redundant "content" line, it also makes the "Contents" heading too large