# How to make memoir's \tableofcontents behave like starred \tableofcontents* by default?

Tags: table-of-contents, memoir, documentclass-writing

I am writing a class based on `memoir`, which provides `\tableofcontents` (which lists the ToC within the ToC) and `\tableofcontents*` (which does not list the ToC within the ToC).

I have seen [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3879/hiding-the-table-of-contents-page-from-table-of-contents) and its many duplicates, but I want to prevent the Table of Contents from itself being listed in the Table of Contents regardless of the user's choice of `\tableofcontents*` *vs.* `\tableofcontents`.

Based on the `memoir` manual (Section 9.2), I am currently using `etoolbox` to do

```
\pretocmd{\tableofcontents}{\begin{KeepFromToc}}{}{<class warning omitted>}
\apptocmd{\tableofcontents}{\end{KeepFromToc}}{}{<class warning omitted>}
```

which works as expected (both starred and unstarred variants do not write a ToC entry).

Is this a recommended way to do this? Does this method have any bad side effects I've not thought of?

Here is an MWE for any testing you may wish to do:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\pretocmd{\tableofcontents}{\begin{KeepFromToc}}{}{}
\apptocmd{\tableofcontents}{\end{KeepFromToc}}{}{}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents   
\chapter{Test Chapter}
\section{Test Section}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `\tableofcontents` command is defined as

```
> \tableofcontents=macro:
->\@ifstar {\@nameuse {mem@tableofcontents}{01}}{\@nameuse {mem@tableofcontents}{00}}.
```

I had to use `\show\tableofcontents`, because the definition is indirect, via

```
\newlistof{tableofcontents}{toc}{\contentsname}
```

Thus

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\tableofcontents}{%
  \@ifstar{\mem@tableofcontents{01}}
          {\mem@tableofcontents{01}}%
}
\makeatother
```

will do.

Complete example:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\tableofcontents}{%
  \@ifstar{\mem@tableofcontents{01}}
          {\mem@tableofcontents{01}}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\chapter{Test Chapter}
\section{Test Section}

\end{document}
```

With `\tableofcontents*` it would be the same.

Answer (score 4):

Without the `etoolbox` package, you can do something like this:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\makeatletter
\let\oldtableofcontents\tableofcontents
\def\tableofcontents{\@ifstar{\oldtableofcontents*}{\oldtableofcontents*}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents  
\chapter{Test Chapter}
\section{Test Section}

\end{document}
```

(of course, in your `.cls` file you don't need `\makeatletter`, `\makeatother`).